# CSS keep inline-block elements side-by-side

Tags: html, css

I want to put 2 `div` side-by-side and half of the time it doesn't work even though I used `display: inline-block`.

Why did I say half of the time? It's because if my second `div` contains text that doesn't fit the width of the element the entire `div` goes below the first one. But this doesn't happen if the text is short and could fit the width of the second element.

To illustrate please check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2wqfz18/1/)

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.desc-hdr {
  width: 150px;
  /* height: 100%; */
}
.desc-hdr,
.desc-value {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc-list">
  <div class="desc-item">
    <div class="desc-hdr inline-block bold">First Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value inline-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc-item">
    <div class="desc-hdr inline-block bold">Second Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value inline-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque facilisis sit amet tortor id sodales. Aenean id ligula sed augue accumsan maximus sit amet viverra nunc. Vestibulum gravida volutpat dui, nec commodo enim suscipit gravida. Pellentesque
      porta odio ut tempor elementum. Mauris id ex sed tellus sagittis laoreet. Pellentesque fringilla velit nisl, quis tempus augue consequat id. Etiam aliquet finibus facilisis. Proin aliquet, arcu at condimentum elementum, nunc est pharetra est, id
      sollicitudin nisi dolor a est. Cras efficitur arcu a nibh molestie tincidunt. Ut blandit mi sapien, eget tristique erat varius et.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `max-width` on `.inline-block` selector?

Comment: @seemly it looks awkward, with the top of the taller second column aligning to the parent container... the first column is way toward the bottom.

Comment: Visually, it looks exactly the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how `inline-block` works you can use `float: left` on first item instead.

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.desc-hdr {
  width: 150px;
   float: left;
}
.desc-hdr,
.desc-value {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.desc-item {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc-list">
  <div class="desc-item">
    <div class="desc-hdr inline-block bold">First Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value inline-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc-item">
    <div class="desc-hdr inline-block bold">Second Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value inline-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque facilisis sit amet tortor id sodales. Aenean id ligula sed augue accumsan maximus sit amet viverra nunc. Vestibulum gravida volutpat dui, nec commodo enim suscipit gravida. Pellentesque
      porta odio ut tempor elementum. Mauris id ex sed tellus sagittis laoreet. Pellentesque fringilla velit nisl, quis tempus augue consequat id. Etiam aliquet finibus facilisis. Proin aliquet, arcu at condimentum elementum, nunc est pharetra est, id
      sollicitudin nisi dolor a est. Cras efficitur arcu a nibh molestie tincidunt. Ut blandit mi sapien, eget tristique erat varius et.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to separate header from text you can use `display: table-cell`

```css
.inline-block {
  display: table-cell;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.desc-hdr {
  width: 150px;
}
.desc-hdr,
.desc-value {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc-list">
  <div class="desc-item">
    <div class="desc-hdr inline-block bold">First Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value inline-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc-item">
    <div class="desc-hdr inline-block bold">Second Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value inline-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque facilisis sit amet tortor id sodales. Aenean id ligula sed augue accumsan maximus sit amet viverra nunc. Vestibulum gravida volutpat dui, nec commodo enim suscipit gravida. Pellentesque
      porta odio ut tempor elementum. Mauris id ex sed tellus sagittis laoreet. Pellentesque fringilla velit nisl, quis tempus augue consequat id. Etiam aliquet finibus facilisis. Proin aliquet, arcu at condimentum elementum, nunc est pharetra est, id
      sollicitudin nisi dolor a est. Cras efficitur arcu a nibh molestie tincidunt. Ut blandit mi sapien, eget tristique erat varius et.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm, `table-cell` doesn't seem like a bad solution and it seems to work perfectly as well. Does using that approach cross the line in terms of avoiding using tables to lay things out?

Comment: I am not sure you should test it out.

Answer (score 1):

That's because inline-blocks are block containers. They must be rectangles, they can't have shapes like this:

```
      ┌─────┐
      │     │
┌─────┘     │
│           │
│           │
└───────────┘
```

What you can do is float the headers. Then they will become out-of-flow, and overlap the margin box of the following blocks (except if the establish a new block formatting context). The nice thing is that line boxes will shrink so the text will move instead of overlapping.

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.desc-hdr {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.desc-hdr,
.desc-value {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc-list">
  <div class="desc-item">
    <div class="desc-hdr bold">First Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc-item">
    <div class="desc-hdr bold">Second Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque facilisis sit amet tortor id sodales. Aenean id ligula sed augue accumsan maximus sit amet viverra nunc. Vestibulum gravida volutpat dui, nec commodo enim suscipit gravida. Pellentesque
      porta odio ut tempor elementum. Mauris id ex sed tellus sagittis laoreet. Pellentesque fringilla velit nisl, quis tempus augue consequat id. Etiam aliquet finibus facilisis. Proin aliquet, arcu at condimentum elementum, nunc est pharetra est, id
      sollicitudin nisi dolor a est. Cras efficitur arcu a nibh molestie tincidunt. Ut blandit mi sapien, eget tristique erat varius et.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the future we will probable be able to use [`display: run-in`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#run-in-layout) instead of float hacks.

> A run-in box is a box that merges into a block that comes after it,
>   inserting itself at the beginning of that block’s inline-level
>   content. This is useful for formatting compact headlines, definitions,
>   and other similar things, where the appropriate DOM structure is to
>   have a headline preceding the following prose, but the desired display
>   is an inline headline laying out with the text.

Comment: I really like your explanation. Thanks for that! Now what if I don't want the long text to ever be in the same column with the first? Basically I want boxes like you said and not some other weird polygons? Right now your solution gives me this reversed L shape. I just want a box.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Then you can float the headers and let the content be a block-level block formatting context root (e.g. `display: block; overflow: hidden`).

Comment: Now that's perfect! https://jsfiddle.net/h2wqfz18/9/

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `display:inline-block` doesn't automagically put the two elements besides each other. It will put them besides each other **if there is space for both elements**. That being said, you're on the right path; you can also limit/set the width of the elements to "make the space" that you need.

In the following snippet, i have done nothing to control the width, and thus, they fill as much width as they need, not giving space to the other element.

```css
.inline-block{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt, nulla sit amet lacinia fermentum, neque dui dapibus dolor, gravida sagittis nisl risus at arcu. In eget nisi eget massa venenatis luctus. Donec nec finibus lectus. Mauris iaculis fermentum convallis. Donec tempus posuere efficitur. Praesent orci risus, mattis vel urna in, viverra viverra quam. Donec aliquet, lectus vel consequat aliquet, justo velit rutrum libero, mattis interdum neque augue eu mi</div>
<div class="inline-block">Quisque dapibus magna et lorem scelerisque, at pharetra turpis scelerisque. Cras tincidunt risus in dolor imperdiet efficitur dapibus ut augue. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque erat odio, consequat et arcu non, congue ultricies enim. Nam laoreet molestie sem, et dignissim est pretium eget. Nulla aliquam viverra enim ac porta. Vivamus at purus mauris</div>
```

On this snippet however, we have added a width limitation (and removed a white space between the elements that would give us problems):

```css
.inline-block{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.half-width{
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-block half-width">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt, nulla sit amet lacinia fermentum, neque dui dapibus dolor, gravida sagittis nisl risus at arcu. In eget nisi eget massa venenatis luctus. Donec nec finibus lectus. Mauris iaculis fermentum convallis. Donec tempus posuere efficitur. Praesent orci risus, mattis vel urna in, viverra viverra quam. Donec aliquet, lectus vel consequat aliquet, justo velit rutrum libero, mattis interdum neque augue eu mi</div><div class="inline-block half-width">Quisque dapibus magna et lorem scelerisque, at pharetra turpis scelerisque. Cras tincidunt risus in dolor imperdiet efficitur dapibus ut augue. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque erat odio, consequat et arcu non, congue ultricies enim. Nam laoreet molestie sem, et dignissim est pretium eget. Nulla aliquam viverra enim ac porta. Vivamus at purus mauris</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block;` causes the text content to wrap.

It sounds like you want two columns.

You can float both of the divs. You can clear the float afterward to go back to displaying your content in a single-column.

Here is the CSS

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.desc-list { overflow: hidden; /* this is to clear the float */ }
.desc-item {
  width: 150px;
}

.col1 { float: left; }    
.col2 { float: right; }
```

And the HTML markup

```
<div class="desc-list">
  <div class="desc-item col1">
    <div class="desc-hdr bold">First Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc-item col2">
    <div class="desc-hdr bold">Second Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque facilisis sit amet tortor id sodales. Aenean id ligula sed augue accumsan maximus sit amet viverra nunc. Vestibulum gravida volutpat dui, nec commodo enim suscipit gravida. Pellentesque
      porta odio ut tempor elementum. Mauris id ex sed tellus sagittis laoreet. Pellentesque fringilla velit nisl, quis tempus augue consequat id. Etiam aliquet finibus facilisis. Proin aliquet, arcu at condimentum elementum, nunc est pharetra est, id
      sollicitudin nisi dolor a est. Cras efficitur arcu a nibh molestie tincidunt. Ut blandit mi sapien, eget tristique erat varius et.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution,

**1.** You forgot to add inline-block class to your "desc-item" 
divs. So without those parent divs will always be blocks.

**2.** Adding this to your CSS will make sure that each div is **always at 50%.**

```
.desc-item{
  width: 50%;
}
```

**3.** Be careful though because HTML can add a small space between divs by default so even though each measure 50% that small extra space will push the second div down. One solution for this is adding the second div on the same line as the next like so:

```
<div>
</div><div>
</div>
```

It's a bit ugly, but it's a quick easy solution to this problem if it ever comes up. Just be aware that there are more solutions to this that you can search for later if you'd need to.

**Here your update jsfiddle, it should be working now.**
https://jsfiddle.net/h2wqfz18/7/

Comment: Sorry but the Fiddle you provided isn't what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .inline-block,.desc-list {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .bold {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .desc-item {
        width: 100%;
    }

        .desc-item > div {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            min-width:150px;
        }

            .desc-item > div + div {
                width: 75%;
            }
```

```html
<div class="desc-list">
  <div class="desc-item">
    <div class="desc-hdr bold">First Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc-item">
    <div class="desc-hdr bold">Second Header</div>
    <div class="desc-value">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque facilisis sit amet tortor id sodales. Aenean id ligula sed augue accumsan maximus sit amet viverra nunc. Vestibulum gravida volutpat dui, nec commodo enim suscipit gravida. Pellentesque
      porta odio ut tempor elementum. Mauris id ex sed tellus sagittis laoreet. Pellentesque fringilla velit nisl, quis tempus augue consequat id. Etiam aliquet finibus facilisis. Proin aliquet, arcu at condimentum elementum, nunc est pharetra est, id
      sollicitudin nisi dolor a est. Cras efficitur arcu a nibh molestie tincidunt. Ut blandit mi sapien, eget tristique erat varius et.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added this code. .desc-value {
  position:absolute;
}

Comment: This is promising and that's the way I want the text to look like but your solution poses a problem. If I resize the window such that the first `Lorem ipsum...` wraps to the next line, it overlaps the next row.

Comment: Based on the positioning in this answer. I edited the styling to be responsive. Give it try. Click view full screen to let the effects take place.